# chrome extensions: extension.sendRequest (message passing) to same page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

is it possible to send a request using message passing api to the same page that will be listening to it? it dosen't seem to work!

One solution is to setup a listener on some other page and then redirect the request back to the parent page. But it is a hack and i really dont want to do that :(

**EDIT** (updated)

background.html (0)

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({action:'foo'}, function(response) {
    //do stuff
});
```

index.html (1)

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({action:'foo'}, function(response) {
    //do stuff
});
```

background.html (2)

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse) {
    if(request.action=='foo') //do stuff
});
...
...
//the code form (0)
```

from above (1) works but (0) does not :(

**EDIT 2**

from (2)

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse) {
    switch(request.action) {
        case 'foo': //do some stuff here
        break;
    }
});
```

The above switch has grown rather long.. some 30 entries i guess.. plus there is no way to call the switch other than poking the eventlistener. (or am i missing something?)

i want to execute the `case 'foo':`'s code somewhere below it in the same file hence i tried calling it in (0).

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You are thinking in terms of Windows messaging right? What are you trying to accomplish? Seems like setTimout() is probably what you'll have to use.

Comment: well my background page interacts with websql database and there is one complex function. until now i have been running it (that function) through sendRequest method because it was called from index.html. but now the background page itself also has to run the function. so i was thinking if it is possible so that i could do it instead of changing the whole function. how can settimeout be used here?

Comment: Sorry, can you show your function (roughly) you are trying to avoid to change and where it is called? I just don't understand why you are not calling it directly, why do you need request listener for that. What is index.html, some popup?

Comment: well index.html is a page of the app. (not extension http://goo.gl/kS86a) and as for the function code, i will add it now :)

Comment: there was some problem in the previous edit, so i changed it a bit too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out already you can't really send a request to the same page, so as a workaround I would do the following:

```
function requestHandler(request, sendResponse) {
    switch(request.action) {
        case 'foo':
            sendResponse(true);
            break;
        }
}

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse) {
    requestHandler(request, sendResponse);
});

//calling handler directly
requestHandler({action:"foo"}, function(result) {
    //response
});
```

Comment: hmm yes moving the whole thing out is a valid option :D thanks :) also what do you suggest should i keep it as a switch or should i shift to objects? which would be more efficient? as i said the switch is quiet long (about 600 lines) and will grow even longer very fast.

Comment: @Achshar What do you mean by switching to objects? There still should be a master switch somewhere that looks at action and decides which code to run. Maybe just split this switch into smaller functions.

Comment: @Achshar I just looked at your code and you are using `sendResponse` inside the switch, so I edited the answer to take that into consideration.

Comment: i was thinking of something on the line of `var bar = {foo:function() {}, ... } bar[request];` inside requestHandler if there is any advantage of objects over a switch?

Comment: oh yea dont worry about it.. i can take care of that ;) (ref your 2nd comment)

Comment: @Achshar Yeah making an object out of it might be a good idea.

Comment: Alright, i know we're not suppose to be kissy-kissy, smoochie-smoochie in here, but you peeps finally put a tombstone on the 'find out the issue is...' grave for putting BOTH on the same page.. (SERG! +1)